# How to allow access to other site(s) to retrieve data from your site/database?

Tags: php, json, rest

I have 2 sites. Let's call it :

- `A`
- `B`

Website `B` have a nice list of data, and all of its relation.
I want to allow website `A` to access website `B` and load those `data`.

- Of course, Website `A` will need some kind of credentials, api_keys, or password to access into website `B`. Right ? I never done this.
- Then after the credential match, website `B` will return the data back to website `A` as json file.
- Then, website `A` will receive that json file, and load them into HTML and display it.

I hope I am clear enough regarding what my goal is.

Here is what I've tried :

After doing some researches, I came across this [site](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api--net-29785). I really liked it. I finished it all way.Now, I kind of get a sense of RESTful API a little more.

Now, moving on to `code`

---

In my `filters.php` I modify

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic("username");
});
```

---

In my `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/authtest', array('before' => 'auth.basic', function(){
    return return "It's work !";
}));
```

After, I run

**Note**

- `username` = `firstuser`
- `password` = `first_password`

C:\wamp\www\laravel-1
λ `curl --user firstuser:first_password localhost/l4api/public/index.php/authtest`

I see

`It's work !`

---

As of right now, it only return a string.

- How do I do it if I want to return the whole users table in json format ?
- So far, I have not use any `api_key` at all ? Is that bad ?

  Big `thanks` to everyone who involve in this post.

Comment: Laravael provides a toJSON() method on models. If you're building an API you will need some kind of authentication unless you don't mind the data being available publicly to anyone.

Comment: You could just allow access to site A's database directly by creating a "site B" user (restricting it by IP address) and connecting to it over HTTPS (from site B) ... or am I missing something?

Comment: @Joe I will need an authentication, you're right. In fact, right now, I authenticate them through user-name and password. 
Is it good enough ? Should I use `api_key` ? Is there any major diff ?
And if, I decide to use `api_key`. I'll need to store it somewhere, ex. database, right ? 
Or since I know there is only `one` site will need an access into my site, can I just manually set the 'api_key'=>'any-random-number'. 
Any, further suggestion or tips, I loved to take it. Thanks again - Joe.

Comment: It depends on how "restful" you want the API to be. A truly restful API is stateless and thus cannot use cookies. There are a few ways to do stateless authentication, but the key is not to send any secret (eg passwords) information with the request. This is a big subject and not really suited to the comments section of this question.

Comment: @CD001 Ohh wow.. I didn't think of that. I guess I could create a user for site `A`, just like I created other user. 
Connecting to it over HTTPS ? I am not how to do that yet, will I need to purchase the SSL cert right ? 
I want to hold off on that right now.
Restricted by IP address, I like this idea, so I will have to check that at some point in my `filters.php` right ? 
Do you have suggestion regarding where I should check that ? Also, do you know anything about reponse a json file to any request. I'm so new to this. 
So far, thank you guys so much for your tips. :)

Comment: @Joe : According to your first comment, I be able to print out all the data inside my users table now - and yes, they're in json format. :)

Comment: So `User::all()->toJson()` will return your users table as JSON objects yes. Though you should add password to the protected array obviously.

Comment: I noticed, password doesn't show because they're hash($password). Is it the same thing as protected array. I guess, I should research more on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.php` you should add sth like this.

Route::get('/api/distributors', array('before' => 'auth.basic', 'uses'=>'DistributorController@api_index'));

}));

`Controller`

```
<?php 

$user = $distributor->user()->first();

$Data = [


    'user' => $user->toArray(),
    'distributor' => $distributor->toArray(),
    'contacts' => $distributor->contacts()->get()->toArray(),
    'addresses' => $distributor->addresses()->get()->toArray()
];

$json_string = json_encode($Data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

?>
```

---

**Logics**

- query whatever you need
- store them in array index
- encode the data
- make your json pretty before send out

Then, the other site will receive `1` json file that have all the data in it.
They will then need to decode it before , they can load all of them into `HTML/PHP` format.